# How cglib fixing the mock issue in spock

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, spock

I am having below class

```
class TestClientSpec extends Specification {

    TestClient testClient
    RestTemplate restTemplate

    def setup() {
        restTemplate = Mock()
        testClient = new TestClient(restTemplate)
    }

    def 'successful'() {
    
        given:
        def url = 'https://test123'
     
        when:
        testClient.getValue(url)

        then:
        1 * restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Test.class)
    }
}
```

when I try to run this test got below error

```
Cannot create mock for class org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate. Mocking of non-interface types requires a code generation library. Please put an up-to-date version of byte-buddy or cglib-nodep on the class path.
org.spockframework.mock.CannotCreateMockException: Cannot create mock for class org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate. Mocking of non-interface types requires a code generation library. Please put an up-to-date version of byte-buddy or cglib-nodep on the class path.
```

After that I have added cglib dependnecy and it's working fine

`implementation group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version: '3.3.0'`

But not sure why it's throws the above error and how cglib fixing this?

Comment: "But not sure why it's throws the above error and how cglib fixing this?" - The part of the system that is generating the proxy class relies on cglib (or similar).  If cglib isn't there, that code will raise an error.  For "how cglib fixing this" - Not sure how best to address that aside from to say that cglib fixes the error because the error indicates that cglib is missing, so it makes sense that cglib's presence would make the error go away.  The presence of cglib allows the proxy to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spock uses a bytecode generator lib, either `cglib` or `byte-buddy`, to generate classes at runtime in order to be able to mock classes.

The dependencies on these libs are optional, so that you can choose whether to use them or not, as you might as well use some dedicated mock libraries for all your mocking needs (e.g. PowerMock).

How adding a bytecode lib to the classpath can fix this?

Well, by enabling the necessary code in Spock... in case of Cglib, [CglibMockFactory](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/mock/runtime/CglibMockFactory.java#L20).

Spock seems to find out which lib is available to use for mocking at [MockInstantiator](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/9da9608a1a565f93c6e8ebadea5f872754a93d8e/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/mock/runtime/MockInstantiator.java#L28)... if you know Java reflection, doing that kind of thing is not hard, just do something like `Class.forName("org.objenesis.Objenesis")` and if that doesn't throw `ClassNotFoundException` you can use that.